# Auto format an array of strings containing HTML with indentation in PhpStorm/WebStorm

Tags: javascript, regex, phpstorm, webstorm

We write our code for our HTML templates in strings. For readability and maintenance we do it as an array of strings e.g.

```
template: [
     '<div>',
     'some content here',
     '</div>'
].join('');
```

Is there anyway I can get PhpStorm/WebStorm to recognise this and format accordingly to keep indentation, even if it means I have to write some regex or function to do the formatting.

What happens now is when the editor formats the code it removes indentation which is a real pain.

Also can we get PhpStorm/WebStorm to recognise that you are in an array and when you hit enter in a string instead of getting

```
'<div>' +
'</div>'
```

you could get

```
'<div>',
'</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alt+Enter then choose Edit Html Fragment. You can use the autoformatter here and Any changes there will propagate to the string.